# How to change AMI on same instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a free micro instance launched in AWS EC2, I want to change the instance's OS to Cent OS. How would I be able to change the AMI <- (OS Image) of the instance?

**Edit (Solved):**

Terminated existing instance and launched a new one.

Comment: If you find an answer can be accepted, you should do as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer instead of added strange words like "sloved".

Comment: I would like to add that AWS Free Tier charges in hours so you don't have to worry when terminating and launching a new instance. You're still within the free tier as long as all of your free tier eligible t2 or t3.micro instance is running for less than 750 hours.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654676/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-ami-on-an-ec2-instance-with-a-different-ami

Answer (score 27):

You cannot update the `AMI` on an existing instance in AWS. The only way to do that is to **terminate the current instance** and **relaunch the instances** with the desired the `AMI`

**Background**

`AMI` is a special type of virtual appliance that is used to instantiate (create) a virtual machine within the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud ("EC2") and I always refer to it as `.iso` image file.

Now I can use an `.iso` image file of a particular OS say Ubuntu to install it on a partition of my choice and if I want to change the OS on that partition then only way for me to do is by formatting that partition and installing a new OS from its `.iso` image file.

Comment: @nueverest there are ways to solve the problem, one quick way is to using user-data-scripts (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) and get the latest code.

Comment: I was able to solve this by first finding the instance matching a particular "Name" Tag and then getting the server id of the instance matching that "Name".